# PHP Does Not Show All Rows From Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `cart` and I want to return all the rows from it via PHP.

So I coded this:

```
$get_add = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_add = '1'";
$run_add = mysqli_query($con,$get_add);

$cart_items = [];
while($row_results = mysqli_fetch_array($run_add))
{
    $item = array(
        'table_id' => $row_results['table_id'],
        'pro_id' => $row_results['product_id'],
        'pro_title' => $row_results['product_title'],
        'pro_price' => number_format($row_results['product_price'], '0', '', ','),
        'pro_supplier'  => $row_results['product_supplier'],
        'pro_img' => $row_results['product_image'],
    );
    $cart_items[] = $item;

    foreach($cart_items as $cart){
        echo $cart['pro_title']
    }
 }
```

So this works fine but the only problem is that it only shows ONE result. However there are several rows that has same `ip_add` set to `1`.

So I'm begging you to let me know what is my fault and what is the correct way of showing all table rows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `foreach` should be outside your `while()`, no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your inner `foreach` loop outside of `while` like this:

```
while($row_results = mysqli_fetch_array($run_add))
{
    $item = array(
        'table_id' => $row_results['table_id'],
        'pro_id' => $row_results['product_id'],
        'pro_title' => $row_results['product_title'],
        'pro_price' => number_format($row_results['product_price'], '0', '', ','),
        'pro_supplier'  => $row_results['product_supplier'],
        'pro_img' => $row_results['product_image'],
    );
    $cart_items[] = $item;
}

foreach($cart_items as $cart){
    echo $cart['pro_title'];
}
```

Basically, what you are doing will always return the last item of array `$cart_itmes` because it's inside of `while` loop. So, change it to the way I've done in above snippet.

Comment: FINAAAAAALLY! Thank U :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `foreach` loop of `$cart_items` and add it after `while` loop. Because you are appending values in `$cart_items` then you are looping that `$cart_items`, so first time you will get single value, then two values, and then three values so on... One more thing add `;` at the end of `echo $cart['pro_title']` line.

```
while ($row_results = mysqli_fetch_array($run_add)) {
    $item = array(
        'table_id' => $row_results['table_id'],
        'pro_id' => $row_results['product_id'],
        'pro_title' => $row_results['product_title'],
        'pro_price' => number_format($row_results['product_price'], '0', '', ','),
        'pro_supplier' => $row_results['product_supplier'],
        'pro_img' => $row_results['product_image'],
    );
    $cart_items[] = $item;
}

foreach ($cart_items as $cart) {
    echo $cart['pro_title'];
}
```

Adding `foreach` at the end will get all the records in the `$cart_items`.